# Java Polymorphism Subclass Functioncall

Tags: java, polymorphism, subclass

I am pretty sure I can find an answer on Stackoverflow for this question. Unfortunately I do not know the specific formulation to do so.

Given following code I have the problem, that I want to avoid typechecks. The comments will probably describe it better than my words.

Right now I am trying to have a shapesystem where every shape can collide with every possible specificShape.
CollisionClass:

```
public class ShapeCollision {
    public static boolean intersects(RectShape rectShape1, RectShape rectShape2) { return true; }

    public static boolean intersects(LineShape lineShape, RectShape rectShape) { return true; }

    public static boolean intersects(RectShape rectShape1, Shape shape) { return true; }

    public static boolean intersects(LineShape lineShape, Shape shape) { return true; }

    public static boolean intersects(Shape shape1, Shape shape2){ return true; }
}
```

ShapeClasses:

```
public class RectShape extends Shape {
    Vector size;
    public RectShape(Vector pos, Vector size) {
        super(pos);
        this.size = size;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean intersects(IShape shape) {
        return ShapeCollision.intersects(this, shape);
    }
}

public class LineShape extends Shape {
    Vector pos2;
    public LineShape(Vector pos, Vector pos2) {
        super(pos);
        this.pos2 = pos2;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean intersects(IShape shape) {
        return ShapeCollision.intersects(this, shape);
    }
}

public class Shape implements IShape {
    protected Vector pos;
    public Shape(Vector pos) {
        this.pos = pos;
    }
    @Override
    public Vector getPos() {
        return pos;
    }
    @Override
    public void setPos(Vector pos) {
        this.pos = pos;
    }
    @Override
    public void move(Vector movementAmount) {
        pos.add(movementAmount);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean intersects(IShape shape) {
        return ShapeCollision.intersects(this, shape);
    }
}
```

Here is the confusing part for me:

```
Shape rect = new RectShape(new Vector(0,0), new Vector(20,20));
Shape rect2 = new RectShape(new Vector(0,0), new Vector(20,20));
Shape line = new LineShape(new Vector(0,0), new Vector(20,20));

//Since I am saving shape and no specific shapetype, it will pass shape and pick the specific superFunction 
//Right now it calls the intersects(RectShape rectShape1, Shape shape) function due to calling it through the shape variable
rect.intersects(rect2); 
//This calls the intersects(LineShape lineShape, Shape shape) function
rect.intersects(line);    
//This calls the intersects(Shape shape1, Shape shape2) function
ShapeCollision.intersects(rect, line);
```

How can I achieve it without specifying the type of the variable, that the 'correct' function with the subclass parameter is called. (e.g.: (LineShape lineShape, RectShape rectShape))

I do not want to make any typechecks in those functions and call the functions specifically, but to use some DesignPatters or something similar if possible :)

Comment: If I am not wrong Shape class implements IShape and All other classes LineSHape and RactShape extends Shape class.Correct?

Comment: @GauravJeswani you are correct. You can also make a suggestions towards what class structure I should use. I am just curious if this is possible.

Comment: If that is the case how  ShapeCollision.intersects(this, shape); is compiling?

Comment: To answer your question, I will adjust the code so everything is visible. I am not sure what yo uare asking. I think you may have misunderstood something ;)

Comment: Yes please update to code.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is NOT achievable without some type checking inside the functions or some explicit casting done on the Shape instances before passing them to  the function calls.

Of course you could declare the objects references with the specific classes, but i guess that is not really helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Maybe someone will find a way. But from that point of view, would you design the architecture the same way?
The problem with saving specific shapes is that I would have to make a GameObject class for each shape then. I thought about making a class named 'LineObjects' which objects consists of simple lines, and circlestructures. In that case I would have only so much typechecks to do.

Comment: I have to be honest, i didn't really look at your classes' design or logic, that would be a whole other topic. Of course i have just a very shallow understanding of what you are trying to do, but what you can try is to use generic parameters and use them to call the right function. Something like this: 
public static <S1 extends Shape, S2 extends Shape> boolean intersects(S1 shape1, S2 shape2){ *here you do all the type checking to see which method to call* }

This way you can make a single public function and all the other instersects method private. Adds some overhead tho.

Comment: I will add that if you want to make this method static (like you did in the ShapeCollision class), it doesn't make much sense to then call this method from and object instance. You either make it a Shape class' method (static or not)  or a ShapeCollision class' method (i don't want to get into the merit of discussing which is better tho).

Comment: I will try to use generics. Maybe that will help. Still a useful comment :)

@Dreddy-ce I am calling it from the other class, so I have to do less typechecks, since it is calling with the 'right' first parameter, beeing the subclass. So it calls it with RectShape, Shape instead of Shape, Shape